# Creating multiple similar components with an array of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I have a json file with an array of data representing people.

I want to make a component per person. Should I make a component and loop through my data inside my render function or should I loop outside my ReactDOM.render function and pass in a specific piece of data each loop?

Should I do it this way:

```
var PersonBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var person = this.props.data.map(function(person, index) {
          return <div id="person" key={index}>
                 // person stuff here
                  </div>
        });
        return (
                <div>
                  {person}
                </div>
              );
  }

ReactDOM.render(<PersonBox data={mydata} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Or should I do this:

```
var PersonBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
        return (
                <div>
                  // person stuff
                </div>
              );
  }  

mydata.map(function(person, index) {
        ReactDOM.render(<PersonBox data={person} />, document.getElementById('container'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use first variant., you can split your code to small components, for example you can split your code to two components like so

```
var Person = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      Name is <strong>{ this.props.name }</strong>
    </div>
  }
});

var PersonBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var people = this.props.data.map(function(person, index) {
      return <Person key={ index } name={ person.name } />  
    });

    return <div>{ people }</div>
  }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/41694/)